# Holding Python conditions outside loop?

Tags: javascript, python, variables, conditional-statements

So, I learned this bissection search algorithm in **Python** and I'm applying it to find the **approximate** square root of a number. As to the algorithm, it works fine to its limitations, however, something I do frequently in **JavaScript**, is encapsulate conditions inside variables so it is easier to read, e.g:

```
var isGreaterThanFive = num > 5;
if(isGreaterThanFive && otherConditions...)
```

While doing this in JavaScript works absolutely fine, when attempting to do this in Python, my program seems to go into an infinite loop. This is my code in JavaScript:

```
function sqrtOf (x) {
  var min = 0
  var max = x
  var epsylon = 0.001
  var guess = (max + min) / 2 
  var guessNumber = 0;

  //I created these two so it is easier to understand
  var notCloseEnough = Math.abs(Math.pow(guess, 2) - x) >= epsylon;
  var stillPlausible = guess <= x;

  while (notCloseEnough && stillPlausible) {
    guessNumber += 1

    if(Math.abs(Math.pow(guess, 2)) > x) {
      max = guess;
    } else {
      min = guess;
    }

    guess = (max + min) / 2;
  }

  return guess;
}

console.log(sqrtOf(25)); // 5
```

And now in Python:

```
def sqrtOf (x)
  minVal = 0
  maxVal = x
  epsylon = 0.001
  guess = (maxVal + minVal) / 2.0 
  guessNumber = 0;

  notCloseEnough = abs(guess ** 2 - x) >= epsylon
  stillPlausible = guess <= x

  while notCloseEnough and stillPlausible:
    guessNumber += 1

    if abs(guess ** 2) > x:
        maxVal = guess
    else:
        minVal = guess

    guess = (maxVal + minVal) / 2.0

  return guess

print sqrtOf(25)
```

Comment: When you have and assignment, the expression on the right side of the `=` is evaluated before being assigned to the variable.  so `stillPlausibe` is equal to either `True` or `False` by the time the loop is started, and you never do anything to change it.

Comment: Your javascript code has the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

When you wrote

```
notCloseEnough = abs(guess ** 2 - x) >= epsylon
```

you evaluated the statement `abs(guess ** 2 - x) >= epsylon` and assigned its result to `notCloseEnough`. That calculation isn't made again just because you happen to reference its result later in the code.

If you want things to reevaluate, you need a function object. You can define an inner function that has visibility to the outer function's local variables.

```
def sqrtOf (x):
  minVal = 0
  maxVal = x
  epsylon = 0.001
  guess = (maxVal + minVal) / 2.0 
  guessNumber = 0

  def notCloseEnough():
    return abs(guess ** 2 - x) >= epsylon

  def stillPlausible():
    return guess <= x

  while notCloseEnough() and stillPlausible():
    guessNumber += 1

    if abs(guess ** 2) > x:
        maxVal = guess
    else:
        minVal = guess

    guess = (maxVal + minVal) / 2.0

  return guess

print sqrtOf(25)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is nice too, `stillPlausible` is confusing to me. The input should get validated before the loop.

```
def sqrtOf(x):
  minVal = 0
  maxVal = x
  epsylon = 0.001
  guess = (maxVal + minVal) / 2.0
  guessNumber = 0;
  def trytrytry():
    while True:
      yield (abs(guess ** 2 - x) < epsylon, guess - x < epsylon)

  for (closeEnough, stillPlausible) in trytrytry():
    if closeEnough or not stillPlausible:
      break
    guessNumber += 1

    if abs(guess ** 2) > x:
        maxVal = guess
    else:
        minVal = guess

    guess = (maxVal + minVal) / 2.0

  return guess

print sqrtOf(25)
```